# Create animated gif screen captures

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, catalina, graphics, screen-capture

How can I take an animated gif or mp4 screen capture of work I'm doing?

- I need the capture to span more than a single window.
- I prefer not to pay for software to do this, but I'm open to installing open-source with [homebrew Cask](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask).
- Bonus points if the tool is written in golang, like [screenshot](https://github.com/kbinani/screenshot) (but I'd rather have a nice capture UI instead of manually defining capture coordinates in golang source as `screenshot` does)
- I have a MacBook running Catalina.